# Prove $r=xa+yb$ and $x+y=1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analysis

I literally have no idea on how to start:

Let $a,b \in \mathbb{K}$ with $a\leq b$. Show that there are, for every $r\in \mathbb{K}$ with $r\in [a,b]$, elements $x,y\in [0,1]$ with:

$r=xa+yb$ and $x+y=1$

Impulses and suggestions needed!

Comment: Have you tried using the Euclidean Algorithm?

Comment: Hmm, I have also thought of it, but it was never mentioned in the lectures.

Comment: This says that $r$ is a weighted average of $a$ and $b$. You have to find the weights (think percentages) - they sum to $1$. So set $y = 1-x$ and solve for $x$. You can even do this when $r$ is not between $a$ and $b$ if you allow for negative weights.

Comment: I like the percentage one the most. If I solve for x it is $x=\frac{r-b}{a-b}$ with $a\neq b$ and $y=\frac{a-r}{a-b}$ with $a\neq b$. But what does that tell me?

Comment: $[a,b]=\{x\in \mathbb{K} : a\leq x\leq b\}$  so $a\neq b$ and thus the equation is always correct?

Answer (score 1):

If you think in term of geometry $R$ belong to straight line $(AB)$ means $\vec{AR}=t\vec{AB}$.

Furthermore when the point $R$ belongs to the segment $[AB]$ then we have $t\in[0,1]$.

The analogy is evident when you go algebraic:

$r-a=t(b-a)\iff r=(1-t)a+tb$

Just set $x=1-t$ and $y=t$ both in $[0,1]$ and you are done.

---

Let's write all this more formally:

if $a=b$ then $r=1a+0b\quad$ with $x=1$ and $y=0$

if $a<b$ then let set $t=\frac{r-a}{b-a}\in \mathbb K$ since it is a field and $b-a\neq 0$

We have $r-a=t(b-a)\iff r=(1-t)a+tb$ and we set $x=1-t$ and $y=t$.

We still have to show that $t\in[0,1]$.

From $r\in[a,b]\quad$ we get $a\le r\le b$

Subtract $a$ and divide by positive quantity $(b-a)>0\quad$ to get $\quad0\le r-a\le b-a\iff 0\le t\le 1$

Comment: Thank you. I don't understand the proof when you say "We have $r-a=t(b-a)$" ... Why do we have that?

Comment: because we defined $t=\frac{r-a}{b-a}$

Comment: so $r-a=r-a$? which is true and thus we can assume it?

Comment: ?? I do not follow you. We define $t$ as the ratio of two numbers, then try to isolate $r$ by multiplying both side by $b-a$.

Comment: Hmm $t:=\frac{r-a}{b-a}\in \mathbb K$, then $r-a=t(b-a)$ is $r-a=\frac{(r-a))(b-a)}{b-a}$ and hence $r-a=r-a$.

Comment: you are very very confused... you wrote let's $t=\frac 23$ then $3t=2$ is $3\frac 23=2$ and hence $2=2$. what does this achieve ? All I'm doing is expressing $r$ in function of $t$, I have hard time understanding what is blocking you like that.

Comment: I guess I do not get the hang of why you did this $r-a=t(b-a)\iff r=(1-t)a+tb$ I mean I get why but not how what went trough your mind to get there...