# Proof that for every $r\in \mathbb{K}$ with $r\in [a,b]$ there are $x,y\in [0,1]$ with $r=xa+yb$ and $x+y=1$

Tags: analysis, proof-verification

The [question has already been asked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3214737/prove-r-xayb-and-xy-1), but I wanted to know if my proof is correct too.

> Let $a,b \in \mathbb{K}$ with $a\leq b$. Show that there are, for
>   every $r\in \mathbb{K}$ with $r\in [a,b]$, elements $x,y\in [0,1]$
>   with: $r=xa+yb$ and $x+y=1$. Note that $\mathbb{K}$ is an ordered field.

**My proof:**

From $r=xa+yb$ and $x+y=1\iff y=1-x$ we can conclude that $r=(a-b)x+b$ which is a linear function with $x\in [0,1]$, thus bijective. All in all, we have $r: [0,1] \to [a,b], x\mapsto (a-b)x+b$, which pratically means that for every $x\in [0,1]$ there is an $r\in [a,b]$.

Answer (score 1):

Your reasoning is not so right.

It's better use $$r=(r-b)(a-b)^{-1}a+(a-r)(a-b)^{-1}b.$$

Here $x=(r-b)(a-b)^{-1}$ and $y=(a-r)(a-b)^{-1}.$

Comment: Could you elaborate?

Comment: Does this address the OPs solution attempt?

Comment: @ParabolicAlcoholic I added something. See now. For any $r\in[a,b]$ take $x$ and $y$, which I wrote.

Comment: @Arthur For any $r\in[a,b]$ we have now $x$ and $y$, which we need to find.

Comment: I understand that this is a hint to a solution. Is this addressing the OP's solution attempt?

Comment: @Arthur Yes, of course. The OP's reasoning is not so right. See please better his post.

Comment: Can down-voter explain us why did you do it?

Comment: I downvoted because OP said "but I wanted to know if my proof is correct too." and indicated they already HAD a way to look at a correct proof. So a new proof, however good, isn't an answer. The "Your reasoning is not so right" [added after my downvote) is, at some level, an answer to the literal question, but actually pointing out at least one failure point seems like a bare minimum that one should do. I mostly admire (and learn from) your answers, but this one seemed to really miss the main point.

Comment: @John Hughes Thank you! In the similar cases I prefer not up-vote. By the way, see please my comment to the Arthut's comment. It was before your post.

Comment: Fair enough. I too rarely vote either way. :( I should probably get in the habit, with upvotes dominating.

Answer (score 1):

Your attempt is not a proof.

First, you start by workingg with $r = xa + yb$ and $x + y = 1$, but you're trying to prove the *existence* of the numbers $x$ and $y$, so these assumptions don't make any sense.

Second, you say that because $r = (a-b)x + b$ defines a linear map on the interval $0 \le x \le 1$, it's bijective. That's false; many linear maps are not bijective. For instance, the map $x \mapsto 0$ is not bijective on the interval $[0, 1]$. Also...when you say a map is bijective, it's probably a good idea to explicitly state the domain and codomain. The map $x \mapsto x^2$ is bijective on as a map from the positive reals to themselves, but not as a function from the positive reals to the reals.

Finally "which practically means" is a weasel-word phrase which I read as "I can't actually think how to justify this."

There you go. That's a math-teacher's assessment of your work. It's probably not what you wanted to hear, but it's based on 50 years of experience. Take it for what you will.

Comment: Thanks. But it says that $a\leq b$, hence only if $a=b$ one can conclude that $r$ is not bijective. Couldn't I just invert the function, then for every $x$ there is an $r$.

Comment: Sure; you could split into cases (a = b, a != b), and in the second case observe that the function $x \mapsto (a-b)x + b$ in fact is a bijection from $[0, 1]$ to $[a, b]$; you could do this by observing that $u \mapsto (a-b)^{-1}(u - b)$ is an inverse to that function, or perhaps by some other technique (depending on what you know about the field $K$). But you didn't do that -- you asserted that "linear" implies "bijection", and that's wrong.

Comment: Yeah, sure it's not about being wrong though. This was a test and I am working on it. So  with the aforementioned corrections, it would be correct?

Comment: Um...I'd say this is a test and **I** have been working on it. Unfortunately, I'm not the one who'll get the credit for any improvement in your grade. 

If I were your prof, I'd be livid. So...I'm done here.

Answer (score 0):

I think the proof is correct , as u r solving 2 linear equation with 2 variables there must exists solution as the lines are not parallel. The solution obtained belong to desired set which is (0,1). As u did it with the general case , this shows that it is true for every case given in the question.